# What shall we do with the 141 unused tags

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-cleanup

There are currently 141 unused tags on EE, not counting [untagged](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). There are irrelevant tags like [australia](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australia), or mysterious ones like [pe](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pe) (poly-ethylene?).

These tags will pop up as suggestions as you start typing part of the word. I think we could discourage their use by deleting them altogether. You would still be able to add them, but then it's a deliberate choice. Now the fact that they appear as suggestion indicates that it's OK to use them, while in many/most cases it isn't, think [australia](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/australia).

So I propose to delete them.

**edit**
I may be misinterpreting. Other tags show the number of questions between brackets, like "(5 x)" next to them, and these don't. Quick survey says there are indeed some unique appearances, others seem to be there as synonyms. I'm not idiotic enough to check them all. As I understand it the synonyms will be automagically converted, so it's possible that the other ones are indeed used, albeit only once.

Comment: How many of these have more then 1 use? Anything with less then 1 use should die in 24 hours, any with only 1 take a month or so, but no further use handles it.

Comment: @Kortuk - Please read my edit. If I'm misinterpreting my question seems to be invalid, and then you can delete it. Sorry, pal.

Comment: Deleting a single tag is not a job for developers as a side note, they are there for 50(or so) or more, for less we will edit ourselves.

Comment: Deleting does not make sense here, it is a perfectly valid question, the answer is just easy to give. I am going to status-declined though. I appreciate teh time you are putting into this, our whole tag system needs lots of work.

Comment: @stevenvh, I saw you killing off [tag:australia]! :)

Comment: @W5VO - Correct, I think the use of that tag is even worse than having it sitting there unused :-)

Comment: How to tell I am tired, I used [meta-tag:status-norepo] for [meta-tag:status-declined]. Did my answer explain the situation well enough?

Comment: @Kortuk - Tired? No, we all thought "our Kortuk is getting old". Yes, it's clear. (Standby for yet another tag question later today.)

Comment: @stevenvh, Ask all you can think of, lets get these tags cleaned up. Once the new moderators are on board I will start making sure we regularly have projects going as we should have more hands then needed on deck.

Comment: @Kortuk - Would it be possible to get a report with all tags with, say, less than 5 occurrences, and the number of occurrences for each?

Comment: @stevenvh Let me look into what can be done with data explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are either single use tags that will die on their own or no use tags the system has not swept out yet. These will clear out on their own.